# Where can I find the wordpress-woocommerce completed order email language file?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, mo

I would like to change a word in the completed order e-mail. I tried to edit the
`wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\i18n\languages\woocommerce-hu_HU.po` file, but it has no effect,the e-mail is the same. 
I would like to change the "Szervusz" in the hungarian file (="Hi there." in english), but there's no other file with this sentence. (Or I couldn't find it.) Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the file is located but it should be a setting (which should be in some type of email setting on the wordpress admin panel for woocommerce)

If you think this part is hardcoded then download your whole plugin folder

then use a mass text search tool like `notepad++` and do a search `Szervusz` in plugin folder

chances are whenever this word comes out will be the location where you need to edit.

after editing just upload the file back.

**just to make sure.. are you sure this isn't in admin setting somewhere?**

Answer (score 0):

It works. I had to save a .mo file too with poedit. First I just edited the .po file with notepad++ and it didn't have an effect on the .mo file. That was the problem.